# Get Facebook user profile details of Amazon AWS Cognito authenticated user android

Tags: android, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I've completed the authentication flow for Users using both UserPool and Federated identities of amazon cognito. I can successfully login using my facebook credentials but i'm not able to get the users public profile information.

I have tried to get the user details by calling the function

```
// Implement callback handler for getting details
    final GetDetailsHandler getDetailsHandler = new GetDetailsHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {
            // The user detail are in cognitoUserDetails
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            // Fetch user details failed, check exception for the cause
        }
    };

cognitoUser.getDetailsInBackground(getDetailsHandler);
```

But its throwing an exception

```
User is not authenticated
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "I can successfully login using my facebook credentials". Did you also [login](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html#tutorial-integrating-user-pools-user-sign-in-javascript) using the Cognito User Pools with username/password? Or did you [federate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html) the Facebook user into Cognito User Pool?

Without these two, trying to retrieve user details from Cognito User Pools will fail with this error.

Comment: What i did is... Federate the facebook user into Cognito User Pool. But still not able to retrieve user public profile information

Comment: Hi Renjithnath Ramachandran, I am also facing issues in authenticating Facebook user. Please help me.